# How do I configure a station exclusively for drop-off or loading in Open TTD?

Tags: openttd

I have an industry whose station is getting pretty overloaded. What I'd like to do is create a second station in the vicinity of the industry and use the stations exclusively for unloading of raw materials and loading of goods, respectively. Can it be done?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can't manually control what stations collect what goods, it's not a function the game provides, but stations simply react to vehicles and will attempt to get any type of good that a vehicle tries to take, once a station starts to collect a good it will do so forever (until it is fully destroyed).

So, if you create two stations a ways apart, and then tell vehicles to only load at one, and only unload at the other:

[image: setting the trucks to only load and only unload]

Then it should work like you want:

[image: all the cities, specifically focusing on Grutburg]

See how Grutburg gathers passengers, and Grutburg Central doesn't?

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. However I already have a station in place that is pushing out goods and I'd like to see if it is possible to use the other station to do that- which means I have to 'turn off' the stations ability (desire?) to receive goods. In addition it is possible for a small screwup in orders to cause a train to land on the sending station intent on receiving, and then the game is up. Both situations require some way of specifying "don't accept resource XYZ at this station", which is (I think) what I'm ultimately after.

Comment: @fbrereto, that's not something which is available in the game - stations react to vehicles and will attempt to get any type of good that a vehicle tries to take, once a station starts to collect a good it will do so forever (until it is fully destroyed).

Comment: @DMA57361: Thanks for the tip; if you make your comment an answer I'll give you proper credit.

Comment: @fbrereto, my comment is merely a small augmentation to this answer, so instead of reposting I've simply edited that detail in more explicitly. Don't worry about giving me "proper credit", I'm not here for the points and if I *was* concerned about that sort of thing I'd of dropped a fully fledged competing answer from the outset. :)

Answer (score 2):

**You can indeed!** Order your raw material trains to *Unload and leave empty*; order your finished goods trains to load. Yes, if you switch around and cease loading at the "producing" station then, for some time, goods will pile up there. But eventually that station's rating for that cargo will drop so low that this becomes a non-issue; production will go (more or less) only to the new pickup station.

Note that this isn't really necessary, though; you can just make a bigger station. Increase station spread and turn *Allow joining stations not directly adjacent **ON***. Now you can build two physical stations joined into one logical station; just hold Ctrl while building. Use **waypoints** and **via orders** to direct traffic.

Also note that if your trains and platforms are different lengths, short trains will prefer the short platforms and long trains, the long ones. You can adjust the penalty for stopping at the "wrong length" platform if you're willing to edit `openttd.cfg` by hand.